# Middleware next js v13 + Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13

I already have a project in my local and I set up a middleware to check some thing before return the next URL. This actually works fine, but when I published in AWS with Amplify it looks like that the middleware is not executed. I'm using pathsextension to check which kind of path will be executed as pages. Someone knows what's happened with this?

I try just a common paths not custom path as home.pages.tsx but still not working. I tried to check amplify if is something wrong but I don't much about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.